# xquery help to query products and users from a different element node

Tags: xquery

please help me to understand how to write this kind of query with xquery.
I have this .xml:

```
<auctions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <products>
  <product id="1">
     <name>Name1</name>
  </product>
  <product id="2">
     <name>Name2</name>
  </product>
  <product id="3">
     <name>Name3</name>
  </product>
  <product id="4">
     <name>Name4</name>
  </product>
</products>
  <users>
<user username="Kukuk1">
</user>
<user username="Kukuk2">
</user>
<user username="Kukuk3">
  </user>
</users>
<bids>
  <product id="1">
    <bid user="Kukuk1">400</bid>
    <bid user="Kukuk2">410</bid>
    <bid user="Kukuk1">450</bid>
  </product>
  <product id="2">
    <bid user="Kukuk3">200</bid>
    <bid user="Kukuk2">300</bid>
  </product>
  <product id="3">
    <bid user="Kukuk1">150</bid>
  </product>
</bids>
</auctions>
```

and I need to get this output, as follows: The user "Kukuk1" got the products "Name1" (with value "450") and "Name3" (with value "150). The user "Kukuk3" has not won any products. The user "Kukuk2" won the products "Name2".

The elements  should be ordered by user ascending and the elements product by value descending, should look like this:

```
 <got>
  <user name="Kukuk1">
    <product value="450">Name1</product>
    <product value="150">Name3</product>
  </user>
  <user name="Kukuk3"/>
  <user name="Kukuk2">
    <product value="300">Name2</product>
  </user>
 </got>
```

This is what I got so far:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:item-separator "&#xa;";
 <got>&#xa;{
  for $u in (//auctions/users/user)
   let $p:= //auctions/products
   let $v := //auctions/bids/product
   let $max1 := max($v/bid)
   let $max2 := max($v/bid[4])
   let $got := //auctions/bids/product
   let $won-product := $got[@id=$p/product/@id]
   order by $u
   return 
      if ($u/@username="Kukuk1") then
              (<user name="{fn:string($u/@username)}"> 
&#xa;<product value="{$max1}">{fn:string($p/product[1]/name)}</product>
&#xa;</user>,'&#xa;')
        else
            if 
            ($u/@username="Kukuk3") then
                (<user name="{fn:string($u/@username)}"> &#xa;<product value="{$max2}">{fn:string($p/product[2]/name)}</product>&#xa;</user>,'&#xa;')
            else
                if
                    ($u/@username="Kukuk2") then
                        (<user name="{fn:string($u/@username)}">
 &#xa;<product value="{$max2}">{fn:string($p/product[3]/name)}</product>&#xa;
 </user>,'&#xa;')
                else ()

}
</got>
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
<got>
 <user name="Kukuk1"> 
  <product value="450">Name1</product>
 </user>
 <user name="Kukuk3"> 
  <product value="">Name2</product>
 </user>
 <user name="Kukuk2"> 
  <product value="">Name3</product>
 </user>
</got>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two for loops to achieve the result you describe. In the outer loop you will order the users based on their respective username and in the inner loop you will get the bids and order them by their highest value.

Hence, it should look something like this:

```
<got>{
  for $u in //auctions/users/user
  let $username := $u/@username
  order by $username
  return element user {
    $username,
    for $product in //auctions/bids/product[bid/@user = $username]
    let $highest-bid := max($product/bid)
    order by $highest-bid descending
    return
      if ($product/bid[. = $highest-bid and @user = $username])
      then element product {
        attribute {"value"} {$highest-bid},
        //auctions/products/product[@id = $product/@id]/name/string()
      } else ()
  }
}</got>
```

Please note that your example output does not fit your description as `Kukuk3 > Kukuk2` and therefore should be order that way. I assumed that your description is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a lot of help. The Kuku3 has a valid bid, but did not got the product because his/hers bid was 200 and the bid from Kukuk2 was 300 :) - how do I get this output, with newlines of course?:

     <got>
       <user name="Kukuk1">
        <product value="450">Name1</product>
        <product value="150">Name3</product>
      </user>
      <user name="Kukuk3"/>
      <user name="Kukuk2">
        <product value="300">Name2</product>
     </user>
  </got>

Comment: @xaoC Ah, I understand  - That wasn't included in your original post. I updated my query accordingly. However, I still don't understand why Kuku3 should be output before Kukuk2 - If you want to order it based on something else than the name you might want to specifiy it. Also, regarding your updated question I ave to say I don't understand your query or what you want to achieve - It seems to be _very_ much tailored to this small data set, wouldn't it make more sense to do it more general without having `if` for specific usernames?

Comment: yes you are right about the small data set. I'm just a beginner and want to lern xquery. My bad with the names - they should be like this to understand. Akuk=Kukuk1, Ckuk=Kukuk2, Bkuk=Kukuk3.